# ipython qtconsole on Windows printing error with no apparent side-effects

Tags: python, ipython, qtconsole

When I launch ipython qtconsole on Windows (by punching `ipython qtconsole` into a CMD window), the following error gets printed quite frequently to CMD:

```
QTextCursor::setPosition: Position '4022' out of range
```

Everything in the ipython qtconsole is working to the best of my knowledge. So I'm curious, what does this error mean, and is it indicative of any underlying problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an IPython [bug](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1392) that's been known for a few years. However, it seems to be a [Qt error](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38178) more than an IPython one.

Neither has been fixed and seems to be very minor.

So, yes there is an underlying problem, but it is not with your code.